# Getting and running latexmk using powershellww

Tags: windows, latexmk

I'm trying to replicate my texlive/sumatrapdf setup which I had running on a Ubuntu virtual machine on my windows machine using powershell. I learned that the equivalent of APT in windows powershell is a tool called Chocolately. I started by running

`choco install texlive`

This appeared to work and I'm able to run `pdflatex` on powershell. However, on my Ubuntu machine I was using `latexmk`, and I'd like to stick with this, since it greatly facilitates compiling tex documents.

I had a look at the chocolatey archive but `latexmk` is nowhere to be found. Furthermore, running `latexmk` in powershell throws an error indicating that it did not install with `texlive` when I ran the `choco install`.

How do I get `latexmk` such that I can compile documents through powershell the same way I was using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by running `tlmgr install latexmk` from an elevated powershell prompt. This is a bit strange because `tlmgr` doesn't work from the ubuntu machine, and I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that it is not correct to install additional packages on the ubuntu machine using `tlmgr`, and I had resorted to using `apt` to install `latexmk`.

Oh well, `tlmgr` seems to work fine in windows. I hope this is not bad practice.

Comment: Tlmgr is "broken/limited" on Linux if you get your latex from a Linux dist. If you install upstream texlive (aka directly from the devs) you have the full power of tlmgr. On windows you install the upstream texlive, so you have the full tlmgr. I have no idea what choco is and what you just installed. Perhaps the choco people did not choose to cripple tlmgr

Comment: `choco` is powershell's version of `apt`